# WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 64 error using Selenium Geckodriver Firefox in FreeBSD jail

Tags: python, selenium, freebsd, geckodriver, selenium4

For some tests, I've set up a plain new TrueNAS 12.3 FreeBSD Jail and started it, then installed `python3`, `firefox`, `geckodriver` and `pip` using the following commands:

```
pkg install python3 firefox geckodriver py38-pip
pip install --upgrade pip
setenv CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST 1
pip install cryptography==3.4.7
pip install selenium
```

Afterwards, when I want to use Selenium with Firefox in my Python code, it does not work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

it brings

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 64
```

Funnily, on another Jail that I've set up approximately a year ago (approximately in the mentioned way as well), it just works and does not throw the error (so different versions maybe?)!

This is the only content of `geckodriver.log`:

```
geckodriver: error: Found argument '--websocket-port' which wasn't expected, orisn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    geckodriver [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]

For more information try --help
```

Is there anything I could try to get it working? I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39163331/4249849), but it seems fairly outdated.

Firefox 95.0.2, geckodriver 0.26.0, Python 3.8.12, Selenium 4.1.0

Comment: What is the Selenium and GeckoDriver version you are using?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Firefox 95.0.2, geckodriver 0.26.0, Python 3.8.12, Selenium 4.1.0

Comment: oops, possibly looking into the error I missed out the last line of the question. I can see it there now

Comment: TL;DR for people with same error message: (a solution may be to) update to: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.30.0

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 64
```

and the [*GeckoDriver*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453) log...

```
geckodriver: error: Found argument '--websocket-port' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

...implies that the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) session.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is ***4.1.0***.
- But your *GeckoDriver* version is ***0.26.0***.

As *`@ernstki`* mentions in their [comment](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1959#issuecomment-1002382891):

> You are running a geckodriver older than 0.30.0, and it is missing the `--websocket-port` option, which newer/new-ish versions of Selenium seem to depend on.

To put it in simple words, till the previous [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073748/which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-3-6-0/47095220#47095220) release of ***v0.29.0*** the `--websocket-port` option wasn't in use, which is now mandatory with ***Selenium v4.0.1***.

Further `@whimboo` also confirmed in his [comment](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1959#issuecomment-1003917216):

> As it has been manifested the problem here is not geckodriver but Selenium. As such you should create an issue on the Selenium repository instead, so that an option could be added to not always pass the --websocket-port argument. If that request gets denied you will have to use older releases of Selenium if testing with older geckodriver releases is really needed.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to current levels [Version 4.1.0](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *GeckoDriver* is upgraded to [GeckoDriver v0.30.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- *Firefox* is upgraded to current *Firefox v96.0.2* levels.

---

### FreeBSD versions

Incase you are using FreeBSD versions where the *GeckoDriver* versions are older, in those cases you have to downgrade *Selenium* to ***v3.x*** levels.

Commands ([**courtesy: Kurtibert**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70821737/webdriverexception-message-service-geckodriver-unexpectedly-exited-status-cod/70822145?noredirect=1#comment125203512_70822145)):

- Uninstall *Selenium*:

  ```
  pip3 uninstall selenium;
  ```
- Install *Selenium*:

  ```
  pip3 install 'selenium<4.0.0'
  ```

Comment: Since my `pkg` doesn't give me anything newer than `0.26.0`, I guess someone has to build a FreeBSD version of geckodriver before new Selenium versions are useable on FreeBSD? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Kurtibert In that case you have to downgrade Selenium to **v3.x** levels. I'd add even that clause to the answer.

Comment: Yeeeees =) I've found out that **v3.141.0** works (if you wish to add it to the answer).
`pip3 uninstall selenium; pip3 install 'selenium<4.0.0'`

Comment: Done updating with the commands

Answer (score 3):

I added the following codes to my dockerfile and my problem was solved. My problems were with the version.

My problem is solved with Selenium 4.1.0 and geckodriver v30.

```
RUN pip install -U selenium==4.1.0
RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.30.0/geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz
RUN tar -x geckodriver -zf geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz -O > /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
RUN rm geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz
```